# Rails 5 - Can anyone explain how generating a URL from non-sanitized request parameters is unsafe?

Tags: security, ruby-on-rails-5

Say I have the following:

`link_to "Excel", params.merge(format: 'xlsx')`

Rails 5 says,

> Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters! An attacker can inject malicious data into the generated URL, such as changing the host. Whitelist and sanitize passed parameters to be secure.

I guess I don't understand how this is unsafe.  Anyone can type anything they want in a browser and perform a GET request to my server anyway.  What's the difference?

I know I can work around it with `permit!`  What I'm trying to understand is what sanitizing my parameters accomplishes.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Comment: @coreyward Rails uses CSRF tokens for POST, I'm talking GET requests.  The message is complaining about a URL I'm generating on my site, so by CSRF are you proposing an attacker craft a url on my site, which when visited contains a generated url to attack some other site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should review the documentation, both from OWASP as well as [Rails itself](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html).

By using `permit`, you have an opportunity to disallow setting attributes that you don't want passed to your url helper.

Consider the following link, directed to your website, coming from a Twitter post:

```
http://example.com/your/action?host=phishingscam.example&path=login
```

If your code looks like this, you're in trouble:

```
link_to 'View Something', params.merge(format: 'xlsx')
```

Now the link goes to:

```
http://phishingscam.example/login.xlsx
```

The attacking website, phishingscam.example, can set the content type to `text/html` and render a page that looks like your login form. The user, who was on your site a moment ago and clicked to view something on your site, believes they got logged out and need to login again. Now our attacker has the user credentials and can redirect them back over to the appropriate link with the user wholly unaware of what happened.

This is a simple scenario. Things can get convoluted pretty quickly. You should [read the Rails security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that was very helpful.  I've actually read the Rails security guide, and unless I'm blind it makes no mention of this (the redirection point is similar).  Other than here on SO and a few people complaining about a pre-updated version of Kaminari google is also coming up short.  If you know of a Rails changelog or a blog post that explains the proper technique of whitelisting my params I'd love to read it.

Comment: @JPDuffy I see you found the commit where the message was added already. ;)

Comment: Yep.  :)  I can't help but feel there should be a better way to do this.  https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cacded5a0e0acc0582c2778b9dd8df684451ad53#commitcomment-18783847

Comment: @JPDuffy All `permit` is really doing is providing you an elegant way of sanitizing input. You can use other options, like `slice` or assembling parameters manually, too. You generally don't want to just pass all user input along to an internal method. That's not even Ruby specific, just a good development practice.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way:

if you have something like this:

```
link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
```

You must include in **permit** the parameters.

You can use this:

```
link_to title, params.permit(:direction, :page).merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
```

Voila!!